# Generate Hashkey from Fingerprint Features

Tags: image-processing, hash, fingerprint

I am working on my project which is minutiae based fingerprint matching in database. We all know that every fingerprint in this world is unique and has unique set of features([Minutiae Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minutiae)). SO is there any way that i could generate a hashkey for a fingerprint image, beacuse searching through hashkey is efficient and i dont have to match in whole database, just match similar hashkeys for fingerprint matching. I am able to extract features from fingerprint image.  Please let me know if there is any technique.

Answer (score 0):

The only method to match fingerprint is to compare fingerprint minutiae:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition

If you need fast match on server against a lot of fingerprints, there's software solutions: [AFIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification).

Here some providers of AFIS solution:

- http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher.html
- http://au.nec.com/en_AU/solutions/security-and-public-safety/biometrics/afis-fingerprint-identification-features.html
- http://www.innovatrics.com/products
- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/afis/
- http://www.m2sys.com/automated-fingerprint-identification-system-afis/

Comment: well thanks, but basically my question was to generate a key from fingerprint minutiae. so that every time i have to match that key , not whole minutiae set.

Comment: @Waqar, It's not possible, as I said the "only" method to match fingerprint is to compare fingerprint minutiae

Comment: @Waqar, is it useful ?